# How to define in TypeScript interface for merge function?

Tags: typescript

There are some way to define such interface for merge function:

```
interface mergeFunc<T, S, P exntends T,S>(t:T, s:S):P;

var merge:mergeFunc = function (t:any, s:any):any {
   var res = {};
   for (let x in t) res[x] = t[x];
   for (let x in s) res[x] = s[x];
   return res;
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript 1.6 (or TypeScript nightly today, use `npm install typescript@next`), you'll be able to use intersection types to write this:

```
declare function mergeFunc<T, S>(t:T, s:S): T & S;
```

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622

Answer (score 0):

**For immutable change of T**

If you only need to merge properties compatible with the initial type, since TypeScript 1.8 you can use type [parameters as constraints](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) :

```
const merge = function<T extends S, S>
( t: T, s: S ) : T {
  const res: any = {}
  // copy
  for ( const k in t ) {
    if ( t.hasOwnProperty ( k ) ) {
      res [ k ] = t [ k ]
    }
  }
  // merge
  for ( const k in s ) {
    if ( s.hasOwnProperty ( k ) ) {
      res [ k ] = s [ k ]
    }
  }
  return res
}
```